# onclick function in html set by updating innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JS function called buyAnimal(id) that works as expected if I set my index.html to include

`<div onclick="buyAnimal(0)"></div>` it works properly, but if I use

```js
let html = `<div onclick="buyAnimal(0)"></div>`
$('#element').html(html);
```

The onclick functionality does not come through, is this normal or do I have to specifically attach an onclick function to that element with my JS?

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a working code snippet

Answer (score -1):

> do I have to specifically attach an onclick function to that element
> with my JS?

You don't need to do that. You can check the below demo.

```js
let html = `<div onclick="buyAnimal(0)">buyAnimal</div>`
$('#element').html(html);

function buyAnimal(id) {
  console.log('buyAnimal', id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should attach event handle to dynamic div by this

```
$(document).on("click", '.buy', function() {
    buyAnimal(0);
});
```

```js
let html = `<div class='buy'>BUY</div>`
$('#element').html(html);
$(document).on("click", '.buy', function() {
    buyAnimal(0);
});

function buyAnimal(n){
   console.log('buy...' + n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```